# Using Green's Theorem to find area enclosed by curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem, parametrization

Use Green's theorem to calculate the area enclosed by the curve:

$x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=4$

Knowing that

$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_c xdy-ydx$

I know that there are already some questions and answers on this site regarding Green's theorem, and I've read many of them. I still really do not know how to proceed, though. Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you struggling with why $A$ is given by the line integral? Or how to evaluate it? Or...?

Comment: @Alex I am mainly struggling with how to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using parametrization can be helpful.

$$ x = 8 \cos ^3 t,~y = 8 \sin ^3 t $$

$$ 2A= \int_C (xdy-ydx) = ~  \int_C (x\dot y-y \dot x )dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I am going to assume you are working over the reals, and make the assumption that $(-x)^{1/3} = -x^{1/3}$. (I.e., we are ignoring the existence of complex solutions.) Then the curve is symmetric about the $x$ and $y$ axes, so you need only compute the area in any of the four quadrants. (It's either this or evaluate the 4 smooth pieces in each quadrant. Either way works, but $3<4$, so why not.)

For this you want to parametrize each piece, and run through the standard line integral computation for each of the three (or four) pieces. Parametrizing the straight lines is not so bad, but for the curve you need to think a little more carefully. Firstly where does it start, and where does it end? (Not only what are the points, but you need to be careful with the choice of orientation for using Green's theorem properly!)

Next, how can we actually write down a parametrization? Well, you can simply set $x=t$, and find out what this forces $y$ to be. In particular, setting $x(t) = t$ will give you a well-defined function $y(t)$ so that the curve is plotted out by $(x(t),y(t))$. With this hand you can now do the standard line integral computation. (Not the nicest of integrals, but doable.)

Let me know if any of the steps are unclear.

Comment: My main problem is that I am not sure what that forces y to be. I know that if the constant in the function were 1, I could set x = cos^3(t) and y = sin^3(t), because then the function would equal 1, but I am not sure how I would have to change that function to accommodate the 4.

Comment: Ah, in my version, setting $x = t$ then means $t^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 4$, and you can solve for $y$. I hadn't even thought about being slick and using trig functions, but that means you can do everything in one calculation, so may be nicer! For this, you have the same idea with circles, parametrizing with $x(t) = r\cos^3(t)$ and $y(t) = r\sin^3(t)$ will get you the 4 for a particular choice of $r$. So when $t=0$, what does $r$ need to be to get that 4?

Comment: @ZachGottschalk (in case you don't get notified about comments on answers on your post)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

@Alex So I tried r=4, but I just realized I think I need $r=4^{3/2}=8$


Yeah, this works and after evaluating the integral I get an answer of $24\pi$

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, $r=8$ looks good!